# What is the equvalent of python command-line argument 'default' when using config file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, configuration-files

I have the following command line argument for a python script:

```
command_parser.add_argument("--wateva", help="Don't care.", default=42)
```

Now I need to switch from command line arguments to config file, because the script has grown so much and it is impossible to pass all the arguments without having a typo.

How do I attach default values for arguments which are read from a config file in Python (i.e. `config = configparser.ConfigParser()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default values can be specified by passing them into the ConfigParser constructor as a dictionary.

```
import ConfigParser

# New instance with 'bar' and 'baz' defaulting to 'Life' and 'hard' each
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser({'bar': 'Life', 'baz': 'hard'})
config.read('example.cfg')

print config.get('Section1', 'foo') # -> "Python is fun!"
config.remove_option('Section1', 'bar')
config.remove_option('Section1', 'baz')
print config.get('Section1', 'foo') # -> "Life is hard!"
```

Comment: how does the `example.cfg` look? How can I use your answer with different sections in the config file?